# Distribution fitting

Tags: r, matlab

I'd like to fit a distribution (any you like) based on these requirements:

1. Produces integer values (preferable but not required)
2. Mean =100
3. Std=114
4. Quantiles( 25%, 50%, 75%)=(6,39,200)
5. Min=0; Max=~300 (but $\infty$ is acceptable);

Poisson fits criteria 1,2 and nearly 3, but not 4 by far. Lognormal... maybe

EXTRA info: value 0 is produced 8% of the time and 300 is produced 18%.

Is it possible to do something like this?  Or do we need more information?

Comment: I'd say you have too much information.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there are infinite possible distributions fitting those criteria.  Generating one that satisfies *all* of them is likely to be hard though. Are you trying to find a theoretical distribution that fits a dataset?

Comment: What's your actual problem? This approach doesn't sound like it will lead to a good solution.

Comment: You can use a maximum entropy to find the distribution that satisfies all of those constraints and provides the maximum entropy.

Comment: @Xi'an Is that approach similar to maximising the goodness of fit of a distribution?  Do you have experience with implementing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function to get you started.

```
function y = weirdrand()

r = rand;
if r < 0.08
    y = 0;
elseif r < 0.25
    y = randsample(1:6, 1);
elseif r < 0.5
    y = randsample(7:39, 1);
elseif r < 0.75
    y = randsample(40:200, 1);
elseif r < 0.82
    y = randsample(201:299, 1);
else
    y = 300;
end

end
```

This obeys rules 1, 4, 5 and the extra info.  `randsample` (from the Stats toolbox) returns one its inputs with equal probability.

Vectorisation is left as an exercise for the reader.  In the meantime,

```
y = arrayfun(@(x) weirdrand(), 1:1e4)
mean(y) %typically around 107
std(y)  %typically around 115
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Looks almost identical to the scatter plot from the paper. Let's see what I can do about vectorising it.

Comment: @user1134241 Your data itself completely defines a distribution. It will be "more perfect", but theoretically *not all that different* if you just took your existing data `x` and used `sample(x, size = n, replace = T)`. *But this is probably useless.* Listen to the comments above and tell us what your actually trying to do.

Comment: @shujaa Thanks for the code string.  It'll be useful for further down the line. At the moment I don't have data, I'm trying to replicate some data from a paper.  There they give a scatter plot and all the criteria (1-5) posted above.

Comment: @user1134241: The better approach would be to get an electronic copy of the paper (scan it if you need to) and retrieve the data with software.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data

Comment: @user1134241 Also useful if you want to do things all in R: http://rdataviz.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/getting-data-from-an-image-introductory-post/

Comment: @RichieCotton That is very interesting, I didn't know this was done.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

(this is actually the same as Xi'an's comment, but I responded independently of him on math.stackexchange.com)

It's certainly possible, but you have more unknowns (301) than constraints (9), which means that you'll have a lot of freedom. One way of restricting that freedom is to use the maximum entropy principle. It will give you the most likely distribution under the constraints.

What you do is maximize $-\sum_i p_i \ln p_i$ under the constraints you have given and where the $p_i$ are the probabilities of all discrete events $i=0,\ldots,300$. You'd best do this numerically.